# Why android studio not showing line where code error?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm debuging a running app and see logcat in  android studio, when the app have a error usually android studio will showing some error detail in logcat with the line where the error happened. but i just get some error detail like this

> 2019-09-04 08:50:46.894 11148-11148/id.co.hallo.hallo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: id.co.hallo.hallo, PID: 11148
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to id.co.hallo.hallo.support.ap
>           at id.co.hallo.hallo.ui.view.residence.setting.SettingResidence$c.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

what should i do to get the detail error with line code where the error happened?

Comment: `view.residence.setting.SettingResidence` this maybe the source of error. Look for the code where you maybe casting a string.

Comment: you may have a try block eating the error.  It's in a non-ui thread for sure.  Look for the cast in your code it's throwing the error on.

Comment: Show us a little bit more of your LogCat message error @norkholis

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to make sure the code in build.gradle proguard is set to false.
- Second, the code you called maybe in a SDK/plugin, so it reminded "unKnown"

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you explain detail of second proccess

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the `LogCat` shows the line of code where the exception is raised, i recommend to you look in the LogCat for the message starting with:

> Caused by

but in this case the exception is pretty obvious, an incorrect cast:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   id.co.hallo.hallo.support.ap

and this error occur in the class:

> id.co.hallo.hallo.ui.view.residence.setting.**SettingResidence**

Comment: should be that, but in my logcat the line where the error has occurred doesn't appear